# Is their a Sheet Feeder for printer HP F2280? Or something not destined exactly for F2280?

Tags: printer

Does any one knows if there is a sheet feeder that I can connect to hp printer F2280?
Or maybe some sheet feeder that not designed for it but works well?
Or is their an option to scan multiple pages at one time (like using sheet feeder)?

Answer (score 0):

It has no attachable options and 50 page sheet feeder is included... I would tend to think that 90% of ink printers are like that.

Comment: What do you mean by "50 page sheet feeder is included"? Can I scan using this sheet feeder?
I know that it has no attachable options, but maybe I can attache some sheet feeder to the computer and it will sync between them?